# apache pig command

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig

just wondering what does the following command means? so hard to google topics related to pig:

```
pig -Dpig.usenewlogicalplan=false
```

i ran the pig script in map/reduce mode, it failed, by adding that flag(-D), it worked, but still have some issue. so what does it mean anyways? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The larger problem is described here: [PIG-1731](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-1731)

It looks like a work around is for you to break your `FILTER`s out onto multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Pig 0.8.0 introduced some bugs in the logical optimizer.  The `-Dpig.usenewlogicalplan=false` option forces a fallback to the earlier version.  Alternatively upgrading to 0.8.1+ should also solve the problem.

Kindly see this for more information
https://books.google.com/books?id=RG-v6qUktSYC&pg=PA96&lpg=PA96&dq=pig.usenewlogicalplan&source=bl&ots=tRH-GSTEkD&sig=z76hSCS036JqQT26zM9lKrXjx-s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CD8Q6AEwA2oVChMIrfj2h-DXyAIVBs5jCh3vTQ7z#v=onepage&q=pig.usenewlogicalplan&f=false

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/Pig+0.9+Backward+Compatibility